# Ways to not pull certain data while using query function in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

In my google spreadsheet I am pulling many line of data from different spreadsheets. currently it pulls all data but I would like to filter it based on the content of a column. So if Column A has xyz, I would not want to import that.

For example Column looks like this

Column A
xyz - 123
abc - 243
xyz - 964
cde - 545
pqr - 654

I would like to write a Query function in which I can say that do not import value if Column A has xyz and my result should show me 

Column A
abc - 243
cde - 545
pqr - 654

Any idea how can I do that?

So far I have been successful in using Like in where but that is other way round of what I am looking for.

Please let me know what to use in query function to no import data which has xyz anywhere in the string.

Thank you

Comment: You want to import data from one sheet to other sheet within the same link or two different URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the following formula:

```
=QUERY(A1:B5, "SELECT A, B WHERE A MATCHES '^((?!xyz).)*$'", 0)
```

[image]